# Password protect a 1 TB Seagate external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, encryption, passwords

I have a 1 TB Seagate external HDD with 700 GB data. I want to put a password on it without any encryption.

I tried BitLocker but it takes 33 hours to encrypt the whole drive and I don't want to wait that long. I just want to put a simple password on it so my 11-year-old niece can't access it.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: If you don't want to encrypt the drive, you can save yourself the trouble. If you just get a dialog for a password but can access the data regardless, it's not going to serve any purpose.

Comment: i just want to put a password so that my 11 year old niece can't access it lol

Comment: Wait 33 hours or put it in a place she doesn't have access to.

Comment: i don't know how to explain, Can you tell me if this is possible or not?

Comment: Yes. Just use an actual encryption tool like BitLocker. It's probably the easiest solution to use. Encrypting a drive is a computing intensive task and all of the data needs to be read and written. So just wait those 33 hours and let it finish the encryption. An alternative would be to put the drive in a locker/safe or similar that your niece doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature called an *ATA password*. It will protect your disk at its firmware level. In Linux use `hdparm` to manage the password, unlock the drive etc. I don't know how Windows deals with this though.

**WARNING:** My practical experience with ATA passwords is limited. I gathered some information and links below but you should do further research ([possible starting point](https://superuser.com/search?q=ata+password)). You can brick your drive if you're not cautious enough.

Things to know:

- If you boot from this particular disk your BIOS (or UEFI) will prompt you for password and unlock the drive. I've read that some BIOS-es don't accept uppercase letters nor special characters ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1062333/432690)).
- There is a user password and a master password. The master password is manufacturer specific and undocumented but you (or your niece) will find all kinds of information about factory presets on the web. It seems [you can change any of them](https://superuser.com/q/357116/432690).
- You said the disk is external. Your (USB?) enclosure may or may not reject the commands that manage ATA password. Some enclosures just don't support them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible - you can't meaningfully lock a USB drive without encrypting it, as plugging it into another device will make it accessible.

Bitlocker is probably the best way to encrypt a drive for a Windows system, otherwise something like Veracrypt could work as well - but both these utilities are going to take a considerable amount of time to lock the drive.
Depending on how full your drive is, you may be able to greatly reduce the amount of time bitlocker takes to encrypt it by turning on "Encrypt with used disk space only" - this will only encrypt the data in use on the drive, which means if you are only using 70 gigs it will take 1-4 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm using 700 gigs, which will take alot of time