# How to disable Windows installation on a PC?

Tags: windows

I have a PC with Windows 7 on it and a password protected user account. I don't want to allow anyone else(let's say my brother) to come in my room, when I am away and make a fresh install of Windows on my PC, as a consequence loosing my data.
I am wondering if there are any software based solutions for preventing this to happen.

From what I've read, BitLocker is used for encryption, this still does not stop someone from booting a DVD disk or a USB flash drive with an operating system setup on it. Will the BitLocker screen appear before allowing installation?

Thank you very much for your time. :)

Comment: Password your BIOS, disable USB port, disable CD/DVD. You won't be able to use those without changing back the setting, though.

Comment: Also: [ATA password](https://superuser.com/a/1225187/432690).

Comment: Your version of Windoes 7 doesn't support Bitlocker.

Comment: You could install a write blocker, but if he figures out its there your brother could remove it.

Comment: This protection will have to exist outside Windows. Setting a BIOS password and disabling all of the boot options except for HDD should do the trick. But... For someone with the right knowledge this still isn't hard to defeat, so it's better to maintain good backups.

Answer (score 2):

Physically remove your hard drive, and ...

1. Place it in a safe
2. Carry it with you

BIOS implementation can be cleared by shorting a jumper or removing the battery and power cord.

Most if not all hard drive protection can be cleared through formatting.

Don't know if a ATA password can be cleared, but my method is protected.

---

You might be better off spending $60 on a second hard drive, and then letting him use that hard drive.  Before you leave for the day shutdown the computer, and switch the sata and power cables.

Comment: Or back up the entire disk, so you can restore it if bro mungs it. Really, though, if someone has physical access to your machine, given time and expertise, they can do virtually anything they want.