# Unlocking hard disk

Tags: hard-drive

I got SATA hard disk from a friend. But it is locked with user password. Both of us don't know the user password or master password. Can I make it possible to use the hard? I don't care about the data inside.

Comment: Is locked in HW, or SW? I mean, is it an expensive HDD with this kind of protection built in, or was it just encrypted using some SW like Windows Bitlocker for example?

Comment: Or is it protected with [ATA password](https://superuser.com/a/1225187/432690)? If you cannot tell then answer this: at what point you are asked for a password? how does the prompt look like? Please [edit] the question and add details.

Comment: The answer that says you can format the disk may be true. And the answer (downvoted and deleted) that says you may not be able to do anything without the password may be true. It depends on the locking method.

Comment: I has to be unlocked on the hardware in which it was locked.

Comment: Agree.  I have run across such disks before.

Comment: I did as you suggested I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the hard drive has been locked with a password, you may not be able to format it. That is one of the purposes of the lock. So the hard drive may not be of any use without the password. This is the case in the majority of the cases.